# JOINT JS orhtogonal links not working properly

Tags: jointjs

I have set my links to be orthogonal in JOINTJS , but still i can see slanting lines. How can i rectify this ?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PZcY.png)

check the right end which is not vertical but slanting . my code is as follows

```
> defaultLink: new joint.dia.Link({
>                 router: { name: 'manhattan' }, 
>                 connection : {name: 'orthogonal'},     
>                 attrs: {
>                 '.marker-target': { d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z', fill: '#fff', stroke: '#000' },
>                 '.link-tools .tool-remove circle, .marker-vertex': { r: 8 },
>                     '.connection': {
>                         stroke: '#000', 'stroke-width': 1
>                         //filter: { name: 'dropShadow', args: { dx: 1, dy: 1, blur: 2 } }
>                     }
>                 }
>             })
```

Comment: Hi, did you maybe find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @pootzko no not yet , moved to https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/docs/toolkit/demo-flowchart-builder.html

Comment: ok, thanks for the reply :)